# Spark: How to aggregate/reduce records based on time difference?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have time series data in CSV from vehicle with following information:

- trip-id
- timestamp
- speed

The data looks like this:

```
trip-id | timestamp  | speed

001     | 1538204192 | 44.55
001     | 1538204193 | 47.20 <-- start of brake
001     | 1538204194 | 42.14
001     | 1538204195 | 39.20
001     | 1538204196 | 35.30
001     | 1538204197 | 32.22 <-- end of brake
001     | 1538204198 | 34.80
001     | 1538204199 | 37.10
...
001     | 1538204221 | 55.30
001     | 1538204222 | 57.20 <-- start of brake
001     | 1538204223 | 54.60
001     | 1538204224 | 52.15
001     | 1538204225 | 49.27
001     | 1538204226 | 47.89 <-- end of brake
001     | 1538204227 | 50.57
001     | 1538204228 | 53.72
...
```

*A braking event occurs when there's a decrease in `speed` in 2 consecutive records based on `timestamp`.*

**I want to extract the braking events from the data in terms of event `start timestamp`, `end timestamp`, `start speed` & `end speed`.**

```
+-------------+---------------+-------------+-----------+---------+
|      breakID|start timestamp|end timestamp|start speed|end speed|
+-------------+---------------+-------------+-----------+---------+
|0011538204193|     1538204193|   1538204196|       47.2|     35.3|
|0011538204222|     1538204222|   1538204225|       57.2|    49.27|
+-------------+---------------+-------------+-----------+---------+
```

Here's my take:

1. Defined a window spec with partition according to `trip-id`, ordered by `timestamp`.
2. Applied window `lag` to move over consecutive rows and calculate speed difference.
3. Filter out records which have positive speed difference, as i am interested in braking events only.
4. Now that I only have records belonging to braking events, I want to group records belonging to same event. I guess i can do this based on the timestamp difference. If the difference between 2 records is 1 second, those 2 records belong to same braking event.

I am stuck here as i do not have a `key` belonging to same group so i can apply key based aggregation.

My question is:

1. How can I **map** to add a `key` column based on the difference in timestamp? So if 2 records have a difference of 1 seconds, they should have a common key. That way, I can reduce a group based on the newly added key.
2. Is there any **better & more optimized** way to achieve this? My approach could be very inefficient as it relies on row by row comparisons. What are the other possible ways to detect these kind of "sub-events" (e.g braking events) in a data-stream belonging to a specific event (data from single vehicle trip)?

Thanks in advance!

---

Appendix:

- Example data file for a trip: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/44a0ilogxp60w...](https://www.dropbox.com/s/44a0ilogxp60wkk/ss_so_trip.zip?dl=0)

Comment: After step 3, how about adding a column for if it the start of a break (eg timestamp is more than 1 greater than the row preceding it) and encode `1` as the start and `0` for all other rows. Then, you could do a cumulative sum on the derived column which would leave all events in the first break labeled `1`, all in the second labeled `1`, etc (eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46979685/calculating-cumulative-sum-in-pyspark-using-window-functions).

Comment: You do not need to think about the timestamp difference at all. You can use a cumulative sum to see which events belong to the same braking event.

Comment: @pault Not sure if i understand that. Could you please explain this a bit more? How would that work out?

Comment: @Shumail  do you want dataframe with no trip-id with just columns start timestamp, end timestamp, start speed & end speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps. Scala code.

**Output**

```
+-------------+---------------+-------------+-----------+---------+
|      breakID|start timestamp|end timestamp|start speed|end speed|
+-------------+---------------+-------------+-----------+---------+
|0011538204193|     1538204193|   1538204196|       47.2|     35.3|
|0011538204222|     1538204222|   1538204225|       57.2|    49.27|
+-------------+---------------+-------------+-----------+---------+
```

**CODE**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

scala> df.show
+-------+----------+-----+
|trip-id| timestamp|speed|
+-------+----------+-----+
|    001|1538204192|44.55|
|    001|1538204193| 47.2|
|    001|1538204194|42.14|
|    001|1538204195| 39.2|
|    001|1538204196| 35.3|
|    001|1538204197|32.22|
|    001|1538204198| 34.8|
|    001|1538204199| 37.1|
|    001|1538204221| 55.3|
|    001|1538204222| 57.2|
|    001|1538204223| 54.6|
|    001|1538204224|52.15|
|    001|1538204225|49.27|
|    001|1538204226|47.89|
|    001|1538204227|50.57|
|    001|1538204228|53.72|
+-------+----------+-----+

val overColumns = Window.partitionBy("trip-id").orderBy("timestamp")
val breaksDF = df
  .withColumn("speeddiff", lead("speed", 1).over(overColumns) - $"speed")
  .withColumn("breaking", when($"speeddiff" < 0, 1).otherwise(0))

scala> breaksDF.show
+-------+----------+-----+-------------------+--------+
|trip-id| timestamp|speed|          speeddiff|breaking|
+-------+----------+-----+-------------------+--------+
|    001|1538204192|44.55| 2.6500000000000057|       0|
|    001|1538204193| 47.2| -5.060000000000002|       1|
|    001|1538204194|42.14|-2.9399999999999977|       1|
|    001|1538204195| 39.2|-3.9000000000000057|       1|
|    001|1538204196| 35.3|-3.0799999999999983|       1|
|    001|1538204197|32.22| 2.5799999999999983|       0|
|    001|1538204198| 34.8| 2.3000000000000043|       0|
|    001|1538204199| 37.1| 18.199999999999996|       0|
|    001|1538204221| 55.3| 1.9000000000000057|       0|
|    001|1538204222| 57.2|-2.6000000000000014|       1|
|    001|1538204223| 54.6| -2.450000000000003|       1|
|    001|1538204224|52.15|-2.8799999999999955|       1|
|    001|1538204225|49.27|-1.3800000000000026|       1|
|    001|1538204226|47.89| 2.6799999999999997|       0|
|    001|1538204227|50.57| 3.1499999999999986|       0|
|    001|1538204228|53.72|               null|       0|
+-------+----------+-----+-------------------+--------+


val outputDF = breaksDF
  .withColumn("breakevent", 
    when(($"breaking" - lag($"breaking", 1).over(overColumns)) === 1, "start of break")
    .when(($"breaking" - lead($"breaking", 1).over(overColumns)) === 1, "end of break"))

scala> outputDF.show
+-------+----------+-----+-------------------+--------+--------------+
|trip-id| timestamp|speed|          speeddiff|breaking|    breakevent|
+-------+----------+-----+-------------------+--------+--------------+
|    001|1538204192|44.55| 2.6500000000000057|       0|          null|
|    001|1538204193| 47.2| -5.060000000000002|       1|start of break|
|    001|1538204194|42.14|-2.9399999999999977|       1|          null|
|    001|1538204195| 39.2|-3.9000000000000057|       1|          null|
|    001|1538204196| 35.3|-3.0799999999999983|       1|  end of break|
|    001|1538204197|32.22| 2.5799999999999983|       0|          null|
|    001|1538204198| 34.8| 2.3000000000000043|       0|          null|
|    001|1538204199| 37.1| 18.199999999999996|       0|          null|
|    001|1538204221| 55.3| 1.9000000000000057|       0|          null|
|    001|1538204222| 57.2|-2.6000000000000014|       1|start of break|
|    001|1538204223| 54.6| -2.450000000000003|       1|          null|
|    001|1538204224|52.15|-2.8799999999999955|       1|          null|
|    001|1538204225|49.27|-1.3800000000000026|       1|  end of break|
|    001|1538204226|47.89| 2.6799999999999997|       0|          null|
|    001|1538204227|50.57| 3.1499999999999986|       0|          null|
|    001|1538204228|53.72|               null|       0|          null|
+-------+----------+-----+-------------------+--------+--------------+


scala> outputDF.filter("breakevent is not null").select("trip-id", "timestamp", "speed", "breakevent").show
+-------+----------+-----+--------------+
|trip-id| timestamp|speed|    breakevent|
+-------+----------+-----+--------------+
|    001|1538204193| 47.2|start of break|
|    001|1538204196| 35.3|  end of break|
|    001|1538204222| 57.2|start of break|
|    001|1538204225|49.27|  end of break|
+-------+----------+-----+--------------+

outputDF.filter("breakevent is not null").withColumn("breakID", 
  when($"breakevent" === "start of break", concat($"trip-id",$"timestamp"))
  .when($"breakevent" === "end of break", concat($"trip-id", lag($"timestamp", 1).over(overColumns))))
  .groupBy("breakID").agg(first($"timestamp") as "start timestamp", last($"timestamp") as "end timestamp", first($"speed") as "start speed", last($"speed") as "end speed").show


+-------------+---------------+-------------+-----------+---------+
|      breakID|start timestamp|end timestamp|start speed|end speed|
+-------------+---------------+-------------+-----------+---------+
|0011538204193|     1538204193|   1538204196|       47.2|     35.3|
|0011538204222|     1538204222|   1538204225|       57.2|    49.27|
+-------------+---------------+-------------+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: Its all good except that the final result is incorrect. I guess it is fixable though, by using `lag` instead of `lead`?

Comment: @C.S.Reddy Gadipally You're a genius! The part where you generate `trip-id` is quite novel. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

For Pandas users, there is pretty much a common programming pattern using `shift()` + `cumsum()` to setup a group-label to identify consecutive rows matching some specific patterns/conditions. With pyspark, we can use Window functions `lag()` + `sum()` to do the same and find this group-label (`d2` in the following code):

### Data Setup:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

>>> df.orderBy('timestamp').show()
+-------+----------+-----+
|trip-id| timestamp|speed|
+-------+----------+-----+
|    001|1538204192|44.55|
|    001|1538204193|47.20|
|    001|1538204194|42.14|
|    001|1538204195|39.20|
|    001|1538204196|35.30|
|    001|1538204197|32.22|
|    001|1538204198|34.80|
|    001|1538204199|37.10|
|    001|1538204221|55.30|
|    001|1538204222|57.20|
|    001|1538204223|54.60|
|    001|1538204224|52.15|
|    001|1538204225|49.27|
|    001|1538204226|47.89|
|    001|1538204227|50.57|
|    001|1538204228|53.72|
+-------+----------+-----+

>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- trip-id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- unix_timestamp: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- speed: double (nullable = true)
```

### Set up two Window Spec (w1, w2):

```
# Window spec used to find previous speed F.lag('speed').over(w1) and also do the cumsum() to find flag `d2`
w1 = Window.partitionBy('trip-id').orderBy('timestamp')

# Window spec used to find the minimal value of flag `d1` over the partition(`trip-id`,`d2`)
w2 = Window.partitionBy('trip-id', 'd2').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
```

### Three flags (d1, d2, d3):

- **d1** : flag to identify if the previous speed is greater than the current speed, if true d1 = 0, else d1 = 1
- **d2** : flag to mark the consecutive rows for speed-drop with the same unique number
- **d3** : flag to identify the minimal value of d1 on the partition('trip-id', 'd2'), only when `d3 == 0` can the row belong to a group with speed-drop. this will be used to filter out unrelated rows

  ```
  df_1 = df.withColumn('d1', F.when(F.lag('speed').over(w1) > F.col('speed'), 0).otherwise(1))\
           .withColumn('d2', F.sum('d1').over(w1)) \
           .withColumn('d3', F.min('d1').over(w2))

  >>> df_1.orderBy('timestamp').show()
  +-------+----------+-----+---+---+---+
  |trip-id| timestamp|speed| d1| d2| d3|
  +-------+----------+-----+---+---+---+
  |    001|1538204192|44.55|  1|  1|  1|
  |    001|1538204193|47.20|  1|  2|  0|
  |    001|1538204194|42.14|  0|  2|  0|
  |    001|1538204195|39.20|  0|  2|  0|
  |    001|1538204196|35.30|  0|  2|  0|
  |    001|1538204197|32.22|  0|  2|  0|
  |    001|1538204198|34.80|  1|  3|  1|
  |    001|1538204199|37.10|  1|  4|  1|
  |    001|1538204221|55.30|  1|  5|  1|
  |    001|1538204222|57.20|  1|  6|  0|
  |    001|1538204223|54.60|  0|  6|  0|
  |    001|1538204224|52.15|  0|  6|  0|
  |    001|1538204225|49.27|  0|  6|  0|
  |    001|1538204226|47.89|  0|  6|  0|
  |    001|1538204227|50.57|  1|  7|  1|
  |    001|1538204228|53.72|  1|  8|  1|
  +-------+----------+-----+---+---+---+
  ```

### Remove rows which are not with concern:

```
df_1 = df_1.where('d3 == 0')

>>> df_1.orderBy('timestamp').show()
+-------+----------+-----+---+---+---+
|trip-id| timestamp|speed| d1| d2| d3|
+-------+----------+-----+---+---+---+
|    001|1538204193|47.20|  1|  2|  0|
|    001|1538204194|42.14|  0|  2|  0|
|    001|1538204195|39.20|  0|  2|  0|
|    001|1538204196|35.30|  0|  2|  0|
|    001|1538204197|32.22|  0|  2|  0|
|    001|1538204222|57.20|  1|  6|  0|
|    001|1538204223|54.60|  0|  6|  0|
|    001|1538204224|52.15|  0|  6|  0|
|    001|1538204225|49.27|  0|  6|  0|
|    001|1538204226|47.89|  0|  6|  0|
+-------+----------+-----+---+---+---+
```

### Final Step:

Now for df_1, group by `trip-id` and `d2`, find the min and max of `F.struct('timestamp', 'speed')` which will return the first and last records in the group, select the corresponding fields from the `struct` to get the final result:

```
df_new = df_1.groupby('trip-id', 'd2').agg(
          F.min(F.struct('timestamp', 'speed')).alias('start')
        , F.max(F.struct('timestamp', 'speed')).alias('end')
).select(
      'trip-id'
    , F.col('start.timestamp').alias('start timestamp')
    , F.col('end.timestamp').alias('end timestamp')
    , F.col('start.speed').alias('start speed')
    , F.col('end.speed').alias('end speed')
)

>>> df_new.show()
+-------+---------------+-------------+-----------+---------+
|trip-id|start timestamp|end timestamp|start speed|end speed|
+-------+---------------+-------------+-----------+---------+
|    001|     1538204193|   1538204197|      47.20|    32.22|
|    001|     1538204222|   1538204226|      57.20|    47.89|
+-------+---------------+-------------+-----------+---------+
```

**Note:** Remove the intermediate dataframe df_1, we can have the following:

```
df_new = df.withColumn('d1', F.when(F.lag('speed').over(w1) > F.col('speed'), 0).otherwise(1))\
           .withColumn('d2', F.sum('d1').over(w1)) \
           .withColumn('d3', F.min('d1').over(w2)) \
           .where('d3 == 0') \
           .groupby('trip-id', 'd2').agg(
                F.min(F.struct('timestamp', 'speed')).alias('start')
              , F.max(F.struct('timestamp', 'speed')).alias('end')
            )\
           .select(
                'trip-id'
              , F.col('start.timestamp').alias('start timestamp')
              , F.col('end.timestamp').alias('end timestamp')
              , F.col('start.speed').alias('start speed')
              , F.col('end.speed').alias('end speed')
            )
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! Do you know of any resource/pointers that has some example implementations with this kind of flag based approach for intermediate data-frames?